# Active site similar to CSS Zen Garden?

Tags: css, html

I like the idea of the [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/) but I seem to have missed the boat on contributing and it has been years since the site was updated.  Has anyone come across a similar type of site that is currently active where people can contribute different designs based on a single html file?

#### Ammendum

Please do not post any more links to random CSS gallery sites.  I understand there are a lot of places to submit and showcase my design chops.

What is interesting about Garden is that everyone was constrained to a certain set of rules and standards, designing specifically for this gallery, with specific standards and framework.   I am looking for similar types of sites that give the template and then maybe rank you or put you in a voting gallery or something.

Having certain limitation and template like this helps spark creativity and I think this is part of the reason for the success of Garden.  I was hoping to find something in this vein that used more cutting edge coding like CSS3 and HTML5 although the rules and standards set with Garden are still relevant for many browsers today.

Answer (score 4):

CSS Garden came into existence at a time when CSS-based layouts were considered a novelty. It was an experiment and a proof-of-concept that was targeted towards web developers/designers, to show them the power of CSS in creating designs/layouts vs the old table-based approach.

That was then.

With time, the purpose of CSS Garden has diminished as CSS is no longer a novelty but the de facto way of creating layout/design.

Now you have CSS galleries.

Nonetheless, even if there are no new postings on CSS Zen Garden, I'm sure you can still download their sample HTML & CSS file, modify the CSS, and upload it on your own personal website to showcase your work. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](http://www.mezzoblue.com/zengarden/faq/), the site still intermittently accepts submissions.

Additionally, these following sites might interest you:
[CSS layouts](http://layouts.ironmyers.com/)
[More layouts](http://www.free-css.com/)
[Great CSS3 Presentation](http://leaverou.me/ft2010/#intro)

Comment: I noticed that.. though I think it is a tease as I have periodically looked at this site over the years and it has not changed.  I think the last update was in 2008 according to wikipedia.

Comment: Well, since I couldn't find anything, I'll give you all my helpful links to CSS sites in the post above.

Comment: Yes those sites do use CSS, but other than that have nothing to do with my question